# Cómo visualizar una aplicación web solo en navegadores web para dispositivos móviles cómo smartphones y tablets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5, css3

Tengo una aplicación web con AngularJS y lo que quiero hacer es que solo se visualice en navegadores web para dispositivos móviles, y si es posible solo en Safari, Chrome, Firefox y Edge. cuando accedan desde un navegador que no sea para dispositivos móviles que muestre una pagina de aviso y también cuando accedan desde un navegador que no sea los ya mencionados. ¿Es posible? y si lo es me darían un ejemplo de cómo implementarlo.

Comment: Busca "userAgent angulajs" en algún buscador y encontrarás lo que buscas. Recuerda que Stackoverflow en español no es un sustituto de Google, por lo que tu pregunta debe plantear un problema específico sobre programación… _preferentemente_.

Comment: Quizás también sería interesante preguntarse por qué querés hacer este filtro, si se deriva de una capacidad que tienen los celulares y tablet de la que carecen los otros navegadores, seguramente lo mejor es intentar utilizarla y dar un aviso al fallar.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que se quiere bloquear un usuario final dependiendo del navegador, y probablemente la razón de esto es el código cliente: establecer **las regla de acceso** en el **código cliente** no parece ser una idea acertada.

Independientemente del framework front-end que estés utilizando para desarrollar la aplicación, el proceso de identificación y la consecuente aplicación de las reglas, tendría que ocurrir antes del bootstrap de tu aplicación.

### Identificar antes de arrancar la aplicación

Este proceso puede ocurrir en el servidor o también en el proceso de carga del front-end (antes de italianizar el framework, que en este caso es AngularJS)

En el caso de backend hecho en Node.js o de una pre-aplicación en cliente, aconsejaría del uso de la librería [ua-parser](http://faisalman.github.io/ua-parser-js/) para identificar el navegador y actuar con respecto al resultado.

En cualquier otro contexto, identifica el [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser) que necesites para tu backend e implementa la condición de *redirect* después del resultado.